# Please explain python 100 >> 5 = 3

Tags: python

I have compiled a list of operators, keywords, etc. and the only one don't understand is >> or << in python.

Please explain the math behind >> and <<.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?

Comment: It is left and right bit shifting. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)

Comment: Yes, I read 5.7 which explains this.  But I am trying to understand the actual math behind it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the [bitwise shift](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operators.  Mathematically, they are equivalent to multiplying (`<<`) or dividing (`>>`) by two to the power of the right operand.

- `x << y` is mathematically equivalent to `x * (2 ** y)`.
- `x >> y` is mathematically equivalent to `x / (2 ** y)`.

They are often used when manipulating or inspecting a bit-flag -- that is, a number whose real meaning is in which bits are turned on or off instead of the apparent numerical value, which is useful to represent a series of booleans in a compact manner.

In your particular case, `100 >> 5` is the same (by the above equivalency) as `100 / (2 ** 5)`.  Simplifying the power operator we get `100 / 32`.  The result of this division is 3.125, but the shift operators are only applicable (by default) to integers, and so the result is truncated.

(These operators are actually implemented as a way to shift the ones and zeroes that constitute a binary number left or right, so the hardware is actually *not* doing division from a mathematical standpoint.  However, if you have a base 10 number "12345" and you shift it right two digits, dropping the fractional part, you get "123".  Essentially, you divided the number by 10 to the power of 2 (or 100) and rounded down, which is precisely the effect that `>>` has -- only in base 2, since computers use base 2 arithmetic.)

Comment: what about operator overloading

Comment: @aaronman Most Python operators can be overloaded, so I don't see any need to specifically call out operator overloading with respect to these two operators.

Comment: just thought it was worth mentioning in case he sees it in other contexts

Comment: "x >> y is mathematically equivalent to x / (2 ** y)" - well, unless x equals ``-1``. Because ``-1`` in Python has infinite number of ones, shifting it to the right always returns ``-1``. It's not something you'd expect until trying to find that infinite loop ;)

Comment: You can clarify the rounding behavior of `>>` by using the "floor division" operator, `//`. This is required in Python 3 (and Python 2 if a `from __future__ import division` statement has been used) where integer division will return a float. Floor division always rounds towards negative infinity, so the situations with negative values that @lqc mentioned are handled correctly: `-1 >> whatever == -1//2**whatever == -1` (negative numbers other than `-1` also work this way).

Answer (score 4):

To understand bit shifting it's best to look at the binary representation

```
>>> bin(100)
'0b1100100'
>>> bin(100>>1)
'0b110010'
>>> bin(100>>2)
'0b11001'
>>> bin(100>>3)
'0b1100'
>>> bin(100>>4)
'0b110'
>>> bin(100>>5)
'0b11'
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> bin(100>>5) == bin(3)
True
```

When you're not thinking in binary, `<< n` is the same as multiply by `2**n`, and `>> n` is the same as divide by `2**n`. The fraction from the division is discarded.

Answer (score 3):

These are the right and left bitshift operators in your case. However python, like many other languages has support for operator overloading so you can use them for other things. In your example `100` is represented in binary as `1100100` when you shift it five digits to the right is is `11`, or base ten 3